# Avoiding exploding gradients when forget gate is 1 and input/output gates are 0

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, lstm

Initially, the cell state equation was $C_t = C_{t-1} + i_t \odot \tanh(w_xx_t + w_hh_{t-1})$. Then to avoid exploding gradients, we added a forget gate such that $$C_t = f_t \odot C_{t-1} + i_t \odot \tanh(w_xx_t + w_hh_{t-1})$$ $$h_t = o_t \odot \tanh(C_t)$$

Consider the following configuration:

1. forget gate $\approx 1 $
2. input/output gate $\approx 0$

With this configuration, it seems that exploding gradients are still possible. How does the partial of the equations prevent exploding gradients given the above configuration. I'm not sure what I'm missing with the math here because if $f_t=~1$, then $C_t$ transposes to $C_t = C_{t-1} + i_t \odot \tanh(w_xx_t + w_hh_{t-1})$ making it susceptible to exploding gradients.

Comment: @Sycorax do you have any thoughts on my question?

Comment: It's not precisely clear to me what the question is. Which thing are you calling the input/output gate? Can you articulate why the configuration you outline will result in exploding gradients? I'm not following the progression.